# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python, image, flask, web-scraping, python-requests

Can anyone please help me out with this error. I am trying to save an image from query string imagle url. but got stuck with the following error.
My code below, please ignore unnecessary libraries

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests
import uuid
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request as urllib
import io

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

abc = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()

class Predict(Resource):
    def get(self):
        url = request.args['url']
        r = requests.get(url)
        fd = urllib.urlopen(r)
        image_file = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
        im = Image.open(image_file)
        return im.save(abc+".png")


api.add_resource(Predict, '/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("", port=7999, debug=True)
```

Output Error :

[image]

Comment: try `fd = urllib.urlopen(url)`,which python version your are using,if is python 3 then use `import urllib2` `fd = urllib2.urlopen(url)`

Comment: `im.save()` returns `None` so your `return im.save(abc+".png")` means `return None`. You should rather return some `Response`.

Comment: if you read image from url then you don't need `Image` to save it but directly open(..., 'wb')` and `write()`

Answer (score 0):

`r = requests.get(url)` returns a response object and you can read it's content by calling r.content, no need to try to open the response object with urlopen to then read it

Answer (score 0):

To save in file you don't need `Image` and `BytesIO()` - you can use directly `open()` and `write()`

If you want to save every image with different name then you should create `abc` inside `get()`

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

#abc = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()  # one name for all images

class Predict(Resource):

    def get(self):
        abc = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()  # generate new name for new image
        filename = abc + '.png'
        #print(filename)

        url = request.args['url']

        r = requests.get(url)

        f = open(filename, 'wb')  # write in bytes-mode 'wb'
        f.write(r.content)
        f.close()

        return {'status': 'OK', 'name': filename}

api.add_resource(Predict, '/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("", port=7999, debug=True)
```

You would need `Image` and `BytesIO` only if you would like to edit image before save.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests
import uuid
from PIL import Image
import io

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

#abc = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper() # one name for all images

class Predict(Resource):

    def get(self):
        abc = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()  # generate new name for new image
        filename = abc + '.png'
        #print(filename)

        url = request.args['url']

        r = requests.get(url)

        fp = io.BytesIO(r.content)
        img = Image.open(fp)

        img = img.resize( (800, 600) )  # resize image

        img.save(filename)

        return {'status': 'OK', 'name': filename}

api.add_resource(Predict, '/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("", port=7999, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks you, its very helpful. But if i want to use the same image in another function.

Comment: if you want to use it in other request then save in file (or database) and later read it from file (or database).